# Universal cover of genus $2$ surface is upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I am learning hyperbolic geometry on my own . I studied about a proof that proves the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ as an universal cover of two holed torus (or genus $2$ surface) using tiling with the hyperbolic octagon.

But I am looking for a prove that the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ can be viewed as the universal cover of a genus $2$ Riemann surface throwing it in complex analysis without using any big theorem like, uniformization theorem.

Please help me. Thanking in advanced

Comment: Is $\mathbb{H}$ the upper half plane for you? If yes, then what is your confusion? A genus two orientable compact closed surface is exactly a two holed torus. If no, then what is $\mathbb{H}$? Or did the proof you studied use some high-power machinery, and you're looking for a simpler proof?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, $\mathbb{H} $ is the upper half plane.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question, then?

Comment: The proof you studied proves exactly what you're asking. Are you looking for a different proof, or are you confused as to why a two holed torus is the same thing as a genus 2 orientable compact closed surface?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I  have edited my question and pointed out what I am exactly want.

Comment: Yes I am asking for a different proof throwing it in complex analysis.

Comment: Well, the UT can be regarded as a result of complex analysis and there are proofs of it, say, in Caratheodoriy's book, which only require classical complex analysis (plus a bit of topology). But before trying to read it, make sure you understand the proof of the Riemann Mapping Theorem.